# Reduce gaps between groups of bars and resize the bar values for each bar

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart, nodes-near-coords

I am trying to reduce the space between the bars and also reduce the space between the values and their bars. As you can see from the figure below, the values of the bars cross the figure boundary.

**My output:**

[image]

**Latex code:**

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc,xcolor={dvipsnames}]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
%\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[
group style={group size=3 by 1}, 
    width=0.33\textwidth, height=1cm,
    xmajorgrids = true,
    tick align = outside, xtick pos = left,
    scale only axis,
    x post scale=0.83,
    enlarge y limits=0.15,
    ytick distance=1,
%   
    xmin=0,xmax=100,
    ytick = data, yticklabels = {N=3,N=6, N=12,N=24},
    xtick={0,20,...,100},
    xticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%},% <-- prints % sign after x tick value
    xticklabel style={font=\scriptsize},
    yticklabel style = {font=\scriptsize},
%    
    nodes near coords style={font=\scriptsize, 
                             yshift={ifthenelse(or(\plotnum == 5,\plotnum == 2),  13pt,13pt)}
                            }, % shift down the third and sixth node
%
    title style = {at={(0.5,-0.3)}, anchor=north},
    legend style={at={(0.5,1.05)}, anchor=south,
                  legend columns=4, font=\footnotesize,
                  cells={anchor=west},
                  /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.5em}
                  }
                    ]
\nextgroupplot[title=(a) MADDPG,
    xbar stacked,
    bar width=3mm,
    y=8mm,
    nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%},
                ]
\addplot [color=black, fill=teal] coordinates{(20.00,1) (18.45,2) (20.00,3) (18.45,4) };
\addplot [color=black, fill=yellow] coordinates{(28.57,1) (28.58,2) (20.00,3) (18.45,4)};
\addplot [color=black, fill=olive] coordinates{(11.43,1) (10.85,2)(20.00,3) (18.45,4)};
% \addplot [color=violet, fill=green] coordinates{(28.57,1) (28.01,2)};
% \addplot [color=violet, fill=orange] coordinates{(6.43,1) (7.55,2)};
\addplot [color=black, fill=orange] coordinates{(5.00,1) (6.56,2) (20.00,3) (18.45,4)};

\nextgroupplot[title=(b) MATD3,
    xbar stacked,
    bar width=3mm,
    y=8mm,
    nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%},
                ]
\addplot [color=black, fill=teal] coordinates{(20.00,1) (18.45,2) (20.00,3) (18.45,4) };
\addplot [color=black, fill=yellow] coordinates{(28.57,1) (28.58,2) (20.00,3) (18.45,4)};
\addplot [color=black, fill=olive] coordinates{(11.43,1) (10.85,2)(20.00,3) (18.45,4)};
% \addplot [color=violet, fill=green] coordinates{(28.57,1) (28.01,2)};
% \addplot [color=violet, fill=orange] coordinates{(6.43,1) (7.55,2)};
\addplot [color=black, fill=orange] coordinates{(5.00,1) (6.56,2) (20.00,3) (18.45,4)};

    %\legend{Action selection, Environment Interactions,   Gradient synchronization},
    \legend{Action selection,   Benchmark learned policies, Calculate rewards,
                    Collect experience, Environment Interactions,   Gradient synchronization},
\nextgroupplot[title=(c) MASAC,
    xbar stacked,
    bar width=3mm,
    y=8mm,
    nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%},
                ]
\addplot [color=black, fill=teal] coordinates{(20.00,1) (18.45,2) (20.00,3) (18.45,4) };
\addplot [color=black, fill=yellow] coordinates{(28.57,1) (28.58,2) (20.00,3) (18.45,4)};
\addplot [color=black, fill=olive] coordinates{(11.43,1) (10.85,2)(20.00,3) (18.45,4)};
% \addplot [color=violet, fill=green] coordinates{(28.57,1) (28.01,2)};
% \addplot [color=violet, fill=orange] coordinates{(6.43,1) (7.55,2)};
\addplot [color=black, fill=orange] coordinates{(5.00,1) (6.56,2) (20.00,3) (18.45,4)};

    \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{Caption text}
\label{fig2}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

To reiterate I want a the values for each bar to be closer and as the values go out of the grid- is there some neat solution for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some changes of your setup (marked) to alternate the position of the values and move them closer to the bar.

`nodes near coords style={yshift={ifthenelse(or(\plotnum == 3,\plotnum == 1),  -7pt,7pt)},font=\tiny},`

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc,xcolor={dvipsnames}]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
%\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure*}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{groupplot}[
                group style={group size=3 by 1}, 
                width=0.33\textwidth, height=1cm,
                xmajorgrids = true,
                tick align = outside, xtick pos = left,
                ytick pos=left,%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< added (supress right ticks)
                scale only axis,
                x post scale=.83,
                enlarge y limits=0.18,%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< changed
                ytick distance=1,    
                xmin=0,xmax=100,
                ytick = data, 
                yticklabels = {N=3,N=6, N=12,N=24},
                xtick={0,20,...,100},
                xticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%},% <-- prints % sign after x tick value
                xticklabel style={font=\scriptsize},
                yticklabel style = {font=\scriptsize},
                %    
                nodes near coords style={
                    yshift={ifthenelse(or(\plotnum == 3,\plotnum == 1),  -7pt,7pt)},
                    font=\tiny,
                }, % shift down the second and fourth node <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< changed
                %
                title style = {at={(0.5,-0.3)}, anchor=north},
                legend style={at={(0.5,1.05)}, anchor=south,
                    legend columns=4, font=\footnotesize,
                    cells={anchor=west},
                    /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.5em}
                }
                ]
                \nextgroupplot[title=(a) MADDPG,
                xbar stacked,
                bar width=3mm,
                y=7mm,%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%},
                ]
                \addplot [color=black, fill=teal] coordinates{(20.00,1) (18.45,2) (20.00,3) (18.45,4) };
                \addplot [color=black, fill=yellow] coordinates{(28.57,1) (28.58,2) (20.00,3) (18.45,4)};
                \addplot [color=black, fill=olive] coordinates{(11.43,1) (10.85,2)(20.00,3) (18.45,4)};
                % \addplot [color=violet, fill=green] coordinates{(28.57,1) (28.01,2)};
                % \addplot [color=violet, fill=orange] coordinates{(6.43,1) (7.55,2)};
                \addplot [color=black, fill=orange] coordinates{(5.00,1) (6.56,2) (20.00,3) (18.45,4)};             
            \end{groupplot}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        
        \caption{Caption text}
        \label{fig2}
    \end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image: b]

This is the complete code with additional changes added to make all three charts fit on the text area.

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc,xcolor={dvipsnames}]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
%\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{showframe} % only to show the margins <<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}         
            \begin{groupplot}[
                group style={group size=3 by 1}, 
                width=0.31\textwidth, height=1cm,%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< changed to fit the text width
                xmajorgrids = true,
                tick align = outside, xtick pos = left,
                ytick pos=left,%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< added (supress right ticks)
                scale only axis,
                x post scale=.83,
                enlarge y limits=0.18,%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< changed
                ytick distance=1,    
                xmin=0,xmax=100,
                ytick = data, 
                yticklabels = {N=3,N=6, N=12,N=24},
                xtick={0,20,...,100},
                xticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%},% <-- prints % sign after x tick value
                xticklabel style={font=\scriptsize},
                yticklabel style = {font=\scriptsize},
                %    
                nodes near coords style={
                    yshift={ifthenelse(or(\plotnum == 1,\plotnum == 3),  -7pt,7pt)},
                    font=\tiny,
                }, % shift down the second and fourth node <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< changed
                %
                title style = {at={(0.5,-0.3)}, anchor=north},
                legend style={at={(0.5,1.05)}, anchor=south,
                    legend columns=4, font=\footnotesize,
                    cells={anchor=west},
                    /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.5em}
                }
                ]
                \nextgroupplot[title=(a) MADDPG,
                xbar stacked,
                bar width=3mm,
                y=7mm,%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%},
                ]
                \addplot [color=black, fill=teal] coordinates{(20.00,1) (18.45,2) (20.00,3) (18.45,4) };
                \addplot [color=black, fill=yellow] coordinates{(28.57,1) (28.58,2) (20.00,3) (18.45,4)};
                \addplot [color=black, fill=olive] coordinates{(11.43,1) (10.85,2)(20.00,3) (18.45,4)};
                \addplot [color=black, fill=orange] coordinates{(5.00,1) (6.56,2) (20.00,3) (18.45,4)}; 

                \nextgroupplot[title=(b) MATD3,
                xbar stacked,
                bar width=3mm,
                y=7mm,%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< changed
                xshift=8pt,%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< added
                nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%},
                ]
                \addplot [color=black, fill=teal] coordinates{(20.00,1) (18.45,2) (20.00,3) (18.45,4) };
                \addplot [color=black, fill=yellow] coordinates{(28.57,1) (28.58,2) (20.00,3) (18.45,4)};
                \addplot [color=black, fill=olive] coordinates{(11.43,1) (10.85,2)(20.00,3) (18.45,4)};
                \addplot [color=black, fill=orange] coordinates{(5.00,1) (6.56,2) (20.00,3) (18.45,4)}; 
                
                \legend{Action selection,   Benchmark learned policies, Calculate rewards,
                        Collect experience, Environment Interactions,   Gradient synchronization};
                
                \nextgroupplot[title=(c) MASAC,
                xbar stacked,
                bar width=3mm,
                y=7mm,%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                xshift=8pt,%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< added
                nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%},
                ]
                \addplot [color=black, fill=teal] coordinates{(20.00,1) (18.45,2) (20.00,3) (18.45,4) };
                \addplot [color=black, fill=yellow] coordinates{(28.57,1) (28.58,2) (20.00,3) (18.45,4)};
                \addplot [color=black, fill=olive] coordinates{(11.43,1) (10.85,2)(20.00,3) (18.45,4)};
                \addplot [color=black, fill=orange] coordinates{(5.00,1) (6.56,2) (20.00,3) (18.45,4)}; 
            \end{groupplot}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Caption text}
        \label{fig2}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: c]